# Popup MaxHeight on Remote Desktop and local machine

Tags: c#, wpf, popup, remote-desktop

I am working on a WPF application which is behaving a little odd when executed on local machine vs remote desktop. I have custom popups shown as drop-down when a ComboBox is clicked. Everything works fine when I access the application from Remote desktop (See the image below)

[image: Remote Desktop Popup (Looks perfect)]

But when I access the same application (no change in code) from my local machine the drop-down popup last row is cut-off (See the image below)

[image: Local computer - Last Row Cutoff]

The same behavior can be seen for all the drop-down popups. How does a specified MaxHeight property behaves differently on local machine and remote desktop?

Following is the code snippet that specifies popup Maxheight:

```
<ComboBox>
    <ComboBox.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="Popup">
            <Setter Property="MaxHeight" Value="114"/>
        </Style>
    </ComboBox.Resources>
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <local:sampleUc />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

Comment: It looks to be due to a difference in resolution, what is the screen resolution of each machine set to?

Comment: Setting the same resolution on Local machine does not solve the issue